# Limit with cos and fraction

Tags: limits

I have been asked to find:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \, \cos \left(\frac{\pi -\pi  \cos ^2(x)}{x^2}\right)$$=-1$

Without using l'Hôpital's rule. But I have no idea how to due it, could someone show a step by step process all the way to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\frac{\pi -\pi\cos^2 x}{x^2}=\frac{\pi\sin^2 x}{x^2}=\pi \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2.$$

As you know, the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \, \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=1$$

Therefore, our answer is:

$$\pi*1 = \pi$$

And

$$\cos(\pi) = -1$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We have 
$$\frac{\pi -\pi\cos^2 x}{x^2}=\frac{\pi\sin^2 x}{x^2}=\pi \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2.$$

Comment: I do not understand why (sinx)/x has limit of one as x approaches zero because sin[0]=1 and when the denominator approaches zero this number should be infinite large what am i missing?

Comment: The fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ is proved in calculus courses, usually geometrically, when one needs the derivative of $\sin x$, for this limit is a critical part of the proof. Note that $\sin 0=0$. If you look back to the differentiation of trigonometric functions part of your book, you will see this limit prominently discussed.

Comment: Unfortunately my book only refers to a proof by the squeeze theorem, but It does not show the proof, would you be able to show me or should I pose a new question?

Comment: It has been done several times on MSE. Yes, it is a squeezing argument. The proof is in a great many places. If you ask the question on MSE, it will probably be quickly closed as a duplicate, but you will have at least one reference. I cannot show you in comments, it really requires a picture.

Comment: You are welcome. I would find it on MSE, but I am not good at searching. I am surprised it is not in your calculus book, it has been in every calculus book I have ever used as a text (many!).